# SQL Server : pivot columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table like this:

| id | EVT | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | M2 | NULL |
| 1 | M3 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2 | M7 | 2024-01-01 |
| 2 | M9 | 2025-01-01 |

i want a table like this:

| id | M1 | M2 | M3 | M7 | M9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | NULL | 2023-01-01 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2024-01-01 | 2025-01-01 |

Do you have a SQL query suggestions to make this transformation ?

I tried :

```
select ID, M1, M2, M3, M7, M9
from Table
pivot (MAX(DATE) FOR EVT in (M1, M2, M3, M7, M9) AS P
```

I got EVT pivoted but a row for each date

| id | M1 | M2 | M3 | M7 | M9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | 2023-01-01 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: If I fix the typographical error in your attempt (`,M9)` should be `,M9))` it works fine. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dIWmO74Z) Voting to close as typographical.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DataSource;

CREATE TABLE #DataSource
(
    [id] INT,
    [EVT] VARCHAR(10),
    [DATE] DATE
);

INSERT INTO #DataSource ([id], [EVT], [DATE])
VALUES (1, 'M1', '2022-01-01'),
       (1, 'M2', NULL),
       (1, 'M3', '2023-01-01'),
       (2, 'M7', '2024-01-01'),
       (2, 'M9', '2025-01-01');

DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @DynamicPIVOTColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @DynamicPIVOTColumns = STRING_AGG(CAST(QUOTENAME([EVT]) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [EVT])
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [EVT]
    FROM #DataSource
   
) DS ([EVT]);

SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = N'
SELECT *
FROM #DataSource
PIVOT
(
    MAX([DATE]) FOR [EVT] IN (' + @DynamicPIVOTColumns + ')
) PVT';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;

DROP TABLE #DataSource;
```

[image]

You can use the following with STRING_AGG is not supported:

```
SET @DynamicPIVOTColumns = STUFF
                          (
                                (
                                SELECT ',[' + CAST([EVT] AS VARCHAR(12)) + ']'
                                FROM #DataSource
                                GROUP BY [EVT]
                                ORDER BY [EVT]
                                FOR XML PATH('') ,TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                                ,1
                                ,1
                                ,''
                          );
```

Comment: Thank you @gotqn. It works in SQL version 2017 and above because the STRING_AGG doesn't exist in previous versions. Do you have some suggestions for SQL 2016. thx